# How a running application on an emulator in Android Studio can act as this?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Trying some code of Jetpack Compose in  Android Studio (Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 2), I was surpised to see the appication running on the emulator acting as interactive as I modified a value in the code window.
I'm precisely speaking of the emulator (Pixel_3a_API_30x86) running the application, not of the Preview (design) window.
How is it possible ? Whitout a new compilation, whithout a new installation ?
If somebody can explain, thanks a lot.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun MyBox(
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  contentAlignModifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
  Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    Text(
      text = stringResource(id = R.string.first),
      fontSize = 20.sp,
      modifier = contentAlignModifier.align(Alignment.TopStart)
    )

    Text(
      text = stringResource(id = R.string.second),
      fontSize = 24.sp,
      modifier = contentAlignModifier.align(Alignment.Center)
    )

    Text(
      text = stringResource(id = R.string.third),
      fontSize = 28.sp,
      modifier = contentAlignModifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
    )
  }

  *// when the application is running on the emulator in Android Studio
  // if I modifiy below the value of Modifier.size
  // I can see immediatly the result on the screen of the emulator
  // How is it possible whithout a new compilation and a new installation ?*
  // **(I'm speaking of the running emulator, not of the preview window...)**

  Box(modifier = Modifier.size(500.dp),
      contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter) {
    Text(
      text = "Voici mon texte !"
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetpack Compose has a `Hot Reload` capability. Similar to that seen in Xamarin.

Comment: Amazing! I didn't know that such a thing was possible.
Thanks Mike

Comment: It’s great for being able to quickly tweak and try layout derivatives, much like when developing web applications, without having to do a rebuild and have the long wait. Enjoy!